# Is there a way to setup Junit 5 as the default, when creating a Gradle project in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5, gradle-dependencies

Is it possible to change the default settings when creating  a gradle project(using the gui in intellij)? for example at the current moment when ever i built a gradle project, in the dependencies the default is junit 4 .Is there a way that i can make change it to junit 5 or do i have to manually add it each time that create a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Here is corresponding request: [IDEA-233256](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233256).